# List full URLs in <link> entity of all Atom feeds

Tags: bug, status-completed, recent-activity, feed

The Atom feeds, particularly "my recent activity", does not contain a full URL in the  entity.

Example:

```
 <link rel="alternate" href="/questions/<id>/<name>" />
```

Should be...

```
 <link rel="alternate" href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/<id>/<name>" />
```

Can this please be tweaked for all the sites? :)

Comment: i'm pretty sure a relative href is perfectly valid, and if your aggregator is failing to handle them it is really a bug in the aggregator

Answer (score 1):

ah, you mean this feed

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/135928/recent

ok, fixed.